# Three digit Number formatter

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to display numbers in 3 digits (001-999). I don't known how to format this number..
I can easily format the decimal numbers, but can't do this.

Answer (score 4):

That's pretty easy... convert your `Number` into a `String`, check its length, and if less than `3`, prepend zeros.

Example:

```
var num:Number = 1;
var numStr:String = num.toString();

while(numStr.length < 3)
{
    numStr = '0' + numStr;
}

trace(numStr); // outputs 001
```

Comment: :: Yeah Its good and it will work but is there any thing with formater functionality?

Comment: @Naju not, there isn't. You should extend NumberFormatter class to add this functionality

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik :: Thank you,I'm going to extend the NumberFormatter

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NumberUtils.format](http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/modules/utils/doc/temple/utils/types/NumberUtils.html#format%28%29) or [StringUtils.padLeft](http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/modules/utils/doc/temple/utils/types/StringUtils.html#padLeft%28%29) to format a Number using the [Temple Library](http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/). The utils are located inside the [utils module](http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/modules/utils/readme.html).

**using `StringUtils.padLeft`**

```
var myValue:int = 3;
trace(StringUtils.padLeft(String(myValue), 3, '0'));
// outputs 003
```

**using `NumberUtils.format`**

```
var myValue:int = 3;
trace(NumberUtils.format(myValue, ',', '.', 0, 3));
// outputs 003
```